# Vim + Tmux: Resetting tmux tab name when exiting vim

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, tmux

I'm labeling my Tmux tabs with the current file in vim like so:

```
autocmd BufEnter * let &titlestring = ' ' . expand("%:t")
set title
set t_ts=k
```

Then I have a VimLeave autocmd to have tmux rename the tab when I exit:

```
autocmd VimLeave * call system("tmux setw automatic-rename")
```

However, when I exit vim, the tab is renamed to "Thanks for flying Vim"

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: There is no need to set the `t_ts` option. If you find that this option is the wrong value in Vim, then you probably just set the wrong `TERM` environment variable. This is probably why restoring the old title doesn't work.

Comment: Oh interesting. My $TERM variable is 'screen'. What should it be set to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'titleold'      string  (default "Thanks for flying Vim")
                global

    This option will be used for the window title when exiting Vim if the
    original title cannot be restored.  Only happens if 'title' is on or
    'titlestring' is not empty.
```

So

```
autocmd VimLeave * set notitle
```

should fix it.